# Render Individual React Components in browser for local development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, widget, mockserver

I am creating a JS Library which acts as a React Widget for a main application. I integration process with the main library is a little complex which makes local development difficult as I have to setup a servers at all times. So what I am seeking is a way to 1st setup a mock server and then somehow render my widget on local host while it feeds of Mock server so I can make my development process seamless. I am rather new to this style of development and would love some guidance on what js technologies/libraries I can look into for achieving above stated goal.

any recommendation on setup for local development of React Libraries is much appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To serve static files locally, you can use serve package https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve